# How to disable the current date and future dates in datepicker using JavaScript or Bootstrap

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label lab col-sm-3" for="dob">Dob</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                     <input type='text' class="form-control" name="dob" />
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
            </div>
   </div>
</body>

<script>
  $(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format : "DD/MM/YYYY",maxDate: moment()});
  });
</script>
```

This function is showing dates and also the current date from the calendar but I don't want the current date to display when I click the calendar button means I want to disable the current date.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you assigned id `datetimepicker1` to `div`. You need to assign id to the `input` **not** to `div`.

```
<div class='input-group date'>
   <input type='text' class="form-control" name="dob" id='datetimepicker1'/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Then `MaxDate` Should be `-1d`. Your code should be like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format : "DD/MM/YYYY",maxDate: "-1d"});
});
```

[Refer Doc for more info](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

Comment: not showing any error but when i click on  calender widget ,it is not displaying any dates

Comment: please anyone help me how to fix this